# Finding shortest Path between two verticies with Parents object

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to Implement a function that prints the shortest path between source and target vertices using a given parents object. The function should return a str that uses " -> " to connect adjacent vertices (see the expected output). How would i go about doing this?

```
def get_path(parents, source, target):
path = ''
### START YOUR CODE ###
pass
### END YOUR CODE ###

return path

# Do not change the test code here
path = get_path(parents, 's', 'z')
print(path)
```

My expected output is:
s -> y -> x -> t -> z

This is what Ive done so far, but it doesnt get me the expected output.

```
def get_path(parents, source, target):
path = [target]
### START YOUR CODE ###
while True:
    key = parents[path[0]]
    path.insert(0, key)
    if key == source:
        break
### END YOUR CODE ###

return path
```

It gives me this: ['s', 'y', 'x', 't', 'z']

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. Have you tried something so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What exactly have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ive edited and showed what ive tried so far, but it isnt the expected output, any help in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: So your only problem is that your output does not include `->`'s? That doesn't seem like a problem to me :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is convert the list to the appropriate string using the `.join()` method.

We first specify our separator:

```py
" -> "
```

Then, we can join the strings in our list using the separator:

```py
" -> ".join(['s', 'y', 'x', 't', 'z'])
```

At which point we get the desired output:

```py
s -> y -> x -> t -> z
```